# coluna com acentuação invalida

Tags: php, sql-server

Estou montando um relatório utilizando o banco de dados de um sistema e PHP com o DBLIB, porém, quem estruturou o banco criou as tabelas e campos com acentuação. Quando eu vou fazer uma consulta em algum campo que não tenha acentuação a query funciona, mas quando acento tem dá erro de coluna invalida.

Exemplo:

```
 select CAST(cp.[vencimento] AS date) as vencimento from contaspagar as cp;  //essa funciona de boa
 select CAST(cp.[dataemissão] AS date) as dataemissao from contaspagar as cp; //essa da erro de coluna invalida
```

Estou usando Linux, PHP 5.6, e a biblioteca freetds para conectar no SQL, SQL 2008 express.

Erro no PHP:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 207 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [207] (severity 16) [(null)]NULL

Significado do erro:

> Invalid column name '%.*ls'.

Comment: Posta a mensagem de erro exata por favor.

Comment: Ygor tem como informar exatamente que ocorre? Se informar talvez consigamos lhe orientar para que funcione.

Comment: @guilherme-nascimento estou montando uma tela em PHP para gerar um relatório, ja consigo fazer a conexão com o banco de dados e executar algumas query, porem algumas tabelas do banco possui acentuação e quando executo a query pelo PHP fala que a coluna esta com nome invalido, mas se executo a query direto no management ela executa normalmente

Comment: Tá mas posta o erro exatamente, se a mensagem de erro exata não temos como deduzir nada.

Comment: coloquei na pergunta

Answer (score 2):

Quando os nome dos identificadores (tabelas colunas ect) têm caracteres acentuados ou outros tipos use os escapes, no caso do SQL SERVER são colchetes (`[]`)

Mude:

```
SELECT descrição FROM ...
```

Para:

```
SELECT [descrição] FROM ...
```

Comment: tentei assim:select CAST([cp.dataemissão] AS date) as dataemissao  e assim: select CAST(cp.[dataemissão] AS date) as dataemissao deu nome da coluna invalida

Comment: @YgorAnjos Deve se assim: `select CAST(cp.[dataemissão] AS date) as dataemissao` os colchotes são individuais ou seja vai para cada coluna

Comment: tentei, mesmo erro :( .... direto no ServeManagement funciona, quando coloco no PHP da erro

Comment: @YgorAnjos qual erro? no SQL Management também dá esse erro?

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 207 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [207] (severity 16) [(null)]NULL  Invalid column name '%.*ls'.

Comment: quando eu coloco outro campo sem acentuação nos colchetes ele executa

Comment: @YgorAnjos pode ser problema no resto da consulta, adiciona ela na pergunta.

Comment: o resto é ...from tabela as cp

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52541/discussion-between-ygor-anjos-and-rray).

Comment: @YgorAnjos quando vc imprime o seu select pelo php (se não testou isso, faça) ele imprime certo? ou ele mostra caracteres estranhos nos acentos?

Comment: foi uma das primeiras coisas que testei, eu estou usando PDO, será que muda algo?

Comment: @YgorAnjos coloca o select completo aqui.

Comment: coloquei na pergunta

Comment: @YgorAnjos tente só `select CAST([dataemissão] AS date) as dataemissao from contaspagar as cp` ou ainda `select CAST(contaspagar.[dataemissão] AS date) as dataemissao from contaspagar`

Comment: esta acontecendo o mesmo erro

Answer (score 2):

Solução:

```
$query=iconv( 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1252', $query );
```

A conexão com o SGBD não é UTF-8. FreeTDS é Ansi/Windows 1252.